How can I transfer specific filtered data from one database(server1) to another database(server 2) in postgresql?
For Example, I have a PostgreSQL database with multiple schemas and each table under the schemas has one common column like city. I want to transfer the database entry for city like Pune from one server to another. How can I do this with single command?
The basic process I know is as follows:

pg_dump the schema
restore it to the destination server
After restore delete the data from all tables which city !=Pune

